# Why do comma separated placeholder rules not get applied in css?

Tags: css, html, colors, placeholder

If I apply the following rule to an input element with id `#one` then the placeholder color will change,

```
#one::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

But if I use comma separater to combine placeholder rules of different browsers then the color doesn't apply, e.g.

```
#two::-webkit-input-placeholder,
#two::-moz-placeholder{
  color: red;
}
```

Working example:

```css
#one::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}

#two::-webkit-input-placeholder,
#two::-moz-placeholder{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="one" type="text" placeholder="one">
<input id="two" type="text" placeholder="two">
```

Why does the `#two` placeholder not change its color to red?

Answer (score 7):

This is because a browser will only apply a rule form a selector it can fully interpret.
For a webkit type browser `-webkit-input-placeholder` is valid but `-moz-placeholder` is not, so it trashes the entire selector, and vise-versa for a geeko based browser.
The solution is to separate browser specific selectors.

```
#two::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: red;
}
#two::-moz-placeholder{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to give reference from w3c or mdn for this behaviour please?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is now a complete answer, but you could add different classes for each input

```css
#one::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}



#two::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: red;
}
#two::-moz-placeholder{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="one" type="text" placeholder="one">
<input id="two" type="text" placeholder="two">
```

Comment: Why should I do this?

Comment: Musa has the correct answer and explanation..I inspected the shadow dom and everything is working as expected